# prototyping bool functions, undefined Foo

Tags: c

I have wery little code:

```
// prototype
bool Foo();

int main( ... )
{
  if( Foo() == false )
    return 1;

  return 0;
}

bool Foo()
{
  return true;
}
```

What is wrong with this? The compiler (VS 2010) shows a lot of syntax error with ")" and ";" and im not doing it right with my prototype?

Comment: `main( ... )` ? Please don't re-type code from memory. Please use actual, real, code that you've run through a compiler at least once...

Comment: @sarnold: main(...) is perfect recognized C code, indicating variadic parameter list.

Comment: @Ryan: I thought `...` was only allowed after a named parameter had been given.

Comment: Have you `#include`d `<stdbool.h>`?

Comment: @sarnold: sorry, I learned something new just now, I was wrong! Please accept my apologies…

Comment: I have just compiled it with VS2010 and it compiles just fine... Is this the only file in your project?

Comment: @Ryan: That's why we're all here :) After you wrote, I _had_ to go test to make sure _I_ wasn't the one in the wrong: `ISO C requires a named argument before ‘...’`.

Comment: @sarnold: I've seen this kind of code before, therefore thought it was perfectly fine. Plus this piece of code also passes compiling after specifying `-std=c89` for gcc.

Comment: Hrm, my `gcc` still pukes, even with `-std=c89`. Color me confused.  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is that bool is not defined.

It depends how your compiler is set but bool is a type that is frequently not supported without defining it yourself or including it.

I found this :

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tf4dy80a.aspx

Cheers

Jason

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with that specific compiler, but judging from the location of the error it might require `void` for the argument list:

```
bool Foo(void);
```

...for no arguments. (I know that C89 allows an empty argument list for unspecified arguments, but maybe VS2010 doesn't follow this. I know I've worked with proprietary compilers that don't.)

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too. The key is the first error:

```
Missing type specifier; assuming 'int'.
```

This means it can't find a type specifier. It's caused by `bool` not being defined as a data type, and the compiler assuming you are creating a function called `bool` instead.

```
bool      //What the program says
int bool  //What it thinks it means
```

It then gets confused when it sees `Foo`, and almost everything following that.

```
Syntax error: expected ';' but found 'Foo'.
Missing type specifier; assuming 'int'.
Undeclared function 'Foo' (did you mean '(no name)'?); assuming 'extern' returning 'int'.
Syntax error: expected ';' but found 'Foo'.
Missing type specifier; assuming 'int'.
Undeclared identifier 'true' (did you mean 'main'?).
```

The solution: define `bool`. The easiest way to do that is to include the standard Boolean header, by placing this line of code at the top of your program:

```
#include <stdbool.h>
```

This has the added benefits of allowing you to access several standard functions for dealing with Booleans, as well as the `true` and `false` identifiers.